# How can I convert an Object to Inputstream

Tags: java, object, inputstream, objectoutputstream

How can I convert the java Object into a InputStream?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

You write the object (obj in the code below) to the [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), your object you want to convert to an input stream must implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

---

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);


    oos.writeObject(obj);

    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: its a nice test , but not very convenient to save/retrieve jpeg.

Comment: what if obj is not implementing Serializable interface.

Comment: Just add "implements Serializable" to your class.  You may also wish to "generate a serializable UUID" as well, most IDEs will do this for you, like eclipse.  This is so that when you serialize the object across the wire there are not conflicts with similar objects in memory.

Comment: what if the object size is greater than 2gb?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331429/convert-object-to-input-stream-in-java