# akka camel sending case classes as messages

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-camel, akka

I'm currently following the akka-camel integration example in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html.

As transport I'm using jetty:http, like

```
class Orders extends Actor with Producer  {
 def endpointUri = "jetty:http://localhost:8877/"
}
```

same for the endpoint

```
class MyEndpoint extends Consumer {
  def endpointUri = "jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8877/"
  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => { println("here", msg ); sender ! "ok"}
    case _                 => { println("somewhere else") }
  }
}
```

All works fine when sending simple text-messages like

```
val sys = ActorSystem("some-system")
val orders = sys.actorOf(Props[Orders])
val endp = sys.actorOf(Props[MyEndpoint])

orders ? "hello"
```

But things do not work when sending Case-Classes

```
case class B(id:String)

orders ? B("hello")
```

The output states an error with the TypeConversion

> akka.camel.AkkaCamelException: No type converter available to convert
>   from type: de.spring.cases.infrastructure.SerializationSpec.B to the
>   required type: java.io.InputStream with value B(hello) 
>   ...

Caused by:

> org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter
>   available to convert from type:
>   de.spring.cases.infrastructure.SerializationSpec.B to the required
>   type: java.io.InputStream with value B(hello)     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpProducer.createHttpExchange(JettyHttpProducer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpProducer.process(JettyHttpProducer.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   akka.camel.ProducerSupport$ProducerChild.produce(Producer.scala:137)
>     at
>   akka.camel.ProducerSupport$ProducerChild$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Producer.scala:111)
>     ... 9 more

When using an explicit (own) serialization/deserialization between the Object and Array[Byte], things go well.

I read about Camels TypeConversions and wonder, if there is an internal way how to transcode the messages from/to serializable objects. And seeing the recipient side, it would be great to use the messages directly using the 'normal' scala pattern matching in the receive function. Without any additional dispatching using additional fields and manual transcoding.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Camel code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-http/2.1.0/org/apache/camel/component/http/HttpProducer.java#HttpProducer.extractResponseBody%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod%2Corg.apache.camel.Exchange%29), the body content need to be an InputStream. So you have to convert the B Object to InputStream and send it to the Producer. In Java is done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264162/how-can-i-convert-an-object-to-inputstream)

Comment: thats what I referred to as "manually". I meanwhile figured out, that adding the conversions to routes may solve the thing. but still sort of manually.