# How to convert large Object to input stream in java

Tags: java, java-stream, out-of-memory

I am trying to convert an object to inputstream using the below code.

```
 try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ObjectOutputStream dataOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        dataOutput.writeObject(dummyObject);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    }
```

since the size of the object can be slightly greater than 2gb, ByteArrayOutputStream is throwing OutOfMemory.

Any way to convert a big object to input stream in java?

Comment: Why, what on earth are you trying to do. What is `object`?

Comment: what is `object.write` ? what exactly does it accept? is it expecting `ByteArrayOutputStream` or any `OutputStream`

Comment: Don't describe the code you think you need or the steps. Describe the [GOAL](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/117-smart-questions)

Comment: @g00se that's what the heading of the question is.

Comment: That's not a goal. It's a step. [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Please suggest a solution if you have any. The question is pretty straightforward.

Comment: This article might help: https://eliux.github.io/java/tricks/use-java-8-stream-to-deal-very-large-input/

Comment: Where does the "This question already has answers here"-link come from? This is about writing large objects, not just writing to a large stream. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

No, at least for the SUN java runtime, `ObjectOutputStream` works with a `ByteArrayOutputStream` internally, probably for a two-pass processing, where the second pass optimizes the encoding of references.

So, there is no way to serialize Objects of arbitrary size with this `ObjectOutputStream` implementation.

What you can do is re-implement the `ObjectOutputStream` from an open-source-version, where you replace the nested `ByteArrayOutputStream` e.g. by a temporary `RandomAccessFile` or an implementation of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, that does not have that artificial limit of 2GB.

**Note** In case you decide to define an independent implementation: Well consider the asynchronous instatiation of nested classes!